# Input range sliders are not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, range

Problem displaying input type range slider's value. How can I fix this?

```js
function update_SchoolValues(val) {
  if (val == 'Middle') {
    var Length = 1;
    var Hours = 30;
    var Subject = 1000;
    document.getElementById('Length').value = Length;
    document.getElementById('Hours').value = Hours;
    document.getElementById('Subject').value = Subject;
    document.getElementById("Length").innerHTML = Length;
    document.getElementById("Hours").innerHTML = Hours;
    document.getElementById("Subject").innerHTML = Subject;
  } else if (val == 'Element') {
    var Length = 1.6;
    var Hours = 10;
    var Subject = 80000;
    document.getElementById('Length').value = Length;
    document.getElementById('Hours').value = Hours;
    document.getElementById('Subject').value = Subject;
    document.getElementById("Length").innerHTML = Length;
    document.getElementById("Hours").innerHTML = Hours;
    document.getElementById("Subject").innerHTML = Subject;
  } else if (val == 'High') {
    var Length = 0;
    var Hours = 0;
    var Subject = 0;
    document.getElementById('Length').value = Length;
    document.getElementById('Hours').value = Hours;
    document.getElementById('Subject').value = Subject;
    document.getElementById("Length").innerHTML = Length;
    document.getElementById("Hours").innerHTML = Hours;
    document.getElementById("Subject").innerHTML = Subject;
  } else if (val == 'Undefined') {
    document.getElementById('Length').value = 0;
    document.getElementById('Hours').value = 0;
    document.getElementById('Subject').value = 0;
  } else {}
}
```

```css
body,
select,
checkbox {
  font: 14pt sans;
}

#label {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.slidecontainer {
  width: 70%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 70%;
  height: 11px;
  background: lightblue;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  background: #69F;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  background: #69F;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.page {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 90vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10;
  left: -100vw;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

page {
  color: red;
}

.page:target {
  left: 0vw;
  z-index: 1;
}

table.genInfoTable {
  margin: auto;
  font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #333333;
  border: 2px solid #343434;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <table class="genInfoTable">
    <tr>
      <th id="label">Testing</th>
      <td><input type="text" id="One1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="label">School</th>
      <td>
        <select id="School" onChange="update_SchoolValues(this.value);">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="Middle">Middle</option>
          <option value="Element">Element</option>
          <option value="High">High</option>
          <option value="Undefined">Undefined</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="border:none">
        <div id="GeneralDiv" style="visibility:visible" style="border: 0px;">
          <table style="border:none;">
            <tr>
              <th id="label">Length</th>
              <td><input type="Range" min="0" max="15" step="0.2" value="0" id="Length" oninput="document.getElementById('Length').innerHTML = this.value;" class="slider">
                </input>
                <em id="Length" style="font-style: normal;"></em>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th id="label">Hours</th>
              <td><input type="Range" min="0" max="30" step="5" value="0" id="Hours" oninput="document.getElementById('Hours').innerHTML = this.value;" class="slider">
                </input>
                <em id="Hours" style="font-style: normal;"></em>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th id="label">Subject</th>
              <td><input type="Range" min="0" max="10000" step="500" value="0" id="Subject" oninput="document.getElementById('Subject').innerHTML = this.value;" class="slider">
                </input>
                <em id="Subject" style="font-style: normal;"></em>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <em id="Length" style="font-style: normal;"></em> <br>
            <em id="Hours" style="font-style: normal;"></em> <br>
            <em id="Subject" style="font-style: normal;"></em> <br>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Okay.  From the code "<em id="Length"></em>"  should display the slider's value. But not displaying within the <td>. If I use the same  <em id="Hours"></em> after <tr> or <table> it does display the value. But I need to display slider value near the each slider.
Hope you could understand this now.

Comment: I used sliders in different pages, But, I had no problem displaying the corresponding values. But for this, I spent lots of time to figure out. But no luck!

Comment: I've found the source of the issue, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always prevent the duplicate id's since the identifier should be unique in the same document, the main problem comes from the duplicate id's when you fix them, the code will work correctly like :

```js
function update_SchoolValues(val) {
  if (val == 'Middle') {
    var Length = 1;
    var Hours = 30;
    var Subject = 1000;
    document.getElementById('Length').value = Length;
    document.getElementById('Hours').value = Hours;
    document.getElementById('Subject').value = Subject;
    document.getElementById("Length_val").innerHTML = Length;
    document.getElementById("Hours_val").innerHTML = Hours;
    document.getElementById("Subject_val").innerHTML = Subject;
  } else if (val == 'Element') {
    var Length = 1.6;
    var Hours = 10;
    var Subject = 80000;
    document.getElementById('Length').value = Length;
    document.getElementById('Hours').value = Hours;
    document.getElementById('Subject').value = Subject;
    document.getElementById("Length_val").innerHTML = Length;
    document.getElementById("Hours_val").innerHTML = Hours;
    document.getElementById("Subject_val").innerHTML = Subject;
  } else if (val == 'High') {
    var Length = 0;
    var Hours = 0;
    var Subject = 0;
    document.getElementById('Length').value = Length;
    document.getElementById('Hours').value = Hours;
    document.getElementById('Subject').value = Subject;
    document.getElementById("Length_val").innerHTML = Length;
    document.getElementById("Hours_val").innerHTML = Hours;
    document.getElementById("Subject_val").innerHTML = Subject;
  } else if (val == 'Undefined') {
    document.getElementById('Length').value = 0;
    document.getElementById('Hours').value = 0;
    document.getElementById('Subject').value = 0;
  } else {}
}
```

```css
body,
select,
checkbox {
  font: 14pt sans;
}

#label {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.slidecontainer {
  width: 70%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 70%;
  height: 11px;
  background: lightblue;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  background: #69F;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  background: #69F;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.page {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 90vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10;
  left: -100vw;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

page {
  color: red;
}

.page:target {
  left: 0vw;
  z-index: 1;
}

table.genInfoTable {
  margin: auto;
  font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #333333;
  border: 2px solid #343434;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <table class="genInfoTable">
    <tr>
      <th id="label">Testing</th>
      <td><input type="text" id="One1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="label">School</th>
      <td>
        <select id="School" onChange="update_SchoolValues(this.value);">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="Middle">Middle</option>
          <option value="Element">Element</option>
          <option value="High">High</option>
          <option value="Undefined">Undefined</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="border:none">
        <div id="GeneralDiv" style="visibility:visible" style="border: 0px;">
          <table style="border:none;">
            <tr>
              <th id="label">Length</th>
              <td><input type="Range" min="0" max="15" step="0.2" value="0" id="Length" oninput="document.getElementById('Length_val').innerHTML = this.value;" class="slider">
                <em id="Length_val" style="font-style: normal;"></em>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th id="label">Hours</th>
              <td><input type="Range" min="0" max="30" step="5" value="0" id="Hours" oninput="document.getElementById('Hours_val').innerHTML = this.value;" class="slider">
                <em id="Hours_val" style="font-style: normal;"></em>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th id="label">Subject</th>
              <td><input type="Range" min="0" max="10000" step="500" value="0" id="Subject" oninput="document.getElementById('Subject_val').innerHTML = this.value;" class="slider">
                <em id="Subject_val" style="font-style: normal;"></em>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</html>
```

Comment: You made my day! Thank you sooo much.